# Loop over multiple Twitter search queries REST API

Tags: python-2.7, rest, loops, twitter, tweepy

I have a working REST Search API script that pulls tweets according to https://www.karambelkar.info/2015/01/how-to-use-twitters-search-rest-api-most-effectively./

**Problem:** This code works, but pulls tweets with `searchQuery1` and `searchQuery2`. (e.g. tweets with `Prostate Cancer` + `Colon Cancer`).  I don't want this. Instead, I would like to get all of tweets from `searchQuery1` (only tweets with `Prostate Cancer`), and then all of the tweets from `searchQuery2`, (only tweets with `Colon Cancer`). The queries should run separately.

**Goal:** Sequentially loop over X number of search queries (e.g. `searchQuery1`, `searchQuery2`, etc)

Thank you!

```
searchQuery1 = 'Prostate Cancer'  
searchQuery2 = 'Colon Cancer' 


maxTweets = 10000
tweetsPerQry = 100  
fprefix = 'REST' 
sinceId = None
max_id = -1L


tweetCount = 0
with open('/Users/eer/Desktop/' + fprefix + '.' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') + '.json', 'a+') as f: #open file
    while tweetCount < maxTweets: 
        try:

            if (max_id <= 0):
                if (not sinceId):
                    for x,y in zip(searchQuery1,searchQuery2):
                        new_tweets = api.search(q=[searchQuery1, searchQuery2], count=tweetsPerQry)
                else:
                    print "sinceID 1"
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=[searchQuery1, searchQuery2], count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            since_id=sinceId)

            else:
                if (not sinceId):
                    print "not sinceID 2"
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=[searchQuery1, searchQuery2], count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1))
                else:
                    print "sinceID 1"
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=[searchQuery1, searchQuery2], count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1),
                                            since_id=sinceId)
            if not new_tweets:
                print("No more tweets found")
                break                 

            for tweet in new_tweets: 
                f.write(jsonpickle.encode(tweet._json, unpicklable=False) +
                        '\n')


            tweetCount += len(new_tweets) 
            max_id = new_tweets[-1].id

        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print("some error : " + str(e))
            break

print ("Downloaded {0} tweets, Saved to {1}".format(tweetCount, fprefix))
```

Comment: Do you want to want to get all tweets in the last week containing searchQuery1 that do not contain searchQuery2, and then get all tweets in the last week containing searchQuery2 that do not contain searchQuery1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchQuery = ['Prostate Cancer', 'Colon Cancer']
i = 0


maxTweets = 1000
tweetsPerQry = 100  
fprefix = 'REST' 
language = ['en']

sinceId = None
max_id = -1L

tweetCount = 0
print("Downloading max {0} tweets".format(maxTweets))
with open('/Users/eer/Desktop/' + fprefix + '.' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') + '.json', 'a+') as f: 
    while tweetCount < maxTweets: 
        try:
            if (max_id <= 0):
                if (not sinceId):

                    for search in searchQuery:
                        new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery[i], count=tweetsPerQry, languages=language)

                else:
                    for search in searchQuery:
                        new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery[i], count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            since_id=sinceId, languages=language)

            else:
                    print "not sinceID 2"
                    for search in searchQuery:
                        new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery[i], count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1),languages=language)
                else:

                    for search in searchQuery:
                        new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery[i], count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1),
                                            since_id=sinceId, languages=language)
            if not new_tweets:
                print("No more tweets found; checking next query")
                i = i + 1

                try:
                    for search in searchQuery:
                        new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery[i], count=tweetsPerQry, languages=language)
                except IndexError:
                    break

            for tweet in new_tweets:         
                f.write(jsonpickle.encode(tweet._json, unpicklable=False) +
                        '\n')

            tweetCount += len(new_tweets) 
            print("Downloaded {0} tweets".format(tweetCount))
            max_id = new_tweets[-1].id

        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print("some error : " + str(e))
            break

print ("Downloaded {0} tweets, Saved to {1}".format(tweetCount, fprefix))
```

Comment: `searchQuery = ['Prostate Cancer', 'Colon Cancer']`, `i = 0` , `for search in searchQuery:`, and `q = searchQuery[i]` are the relevant new pieces of code. Also, under `if not new_tweets:` There are also a few new lines of code starting from `i = i + 1` that help track the new search query (e.g. `Colon Cancer`) once all tweets from the first query `Prostate Cancer` are done

Answer (score 0):

I would change your query to `'"Prostate Cancer" OR "Colon Cancer"'` and store the results. Then order them how you want later. It sounds like you want the following in pseudo-code:

```
tweets_with_Prostate_Cancer = []
tweets_with_Colon_Cancer = []

for each tweet in the result set:
    if tweet contains "Prostate Cancer" and does not contain "Colon Cancer":
        tweets_with_Prostate_Cancer.Add(tweet)
    if tweet contains "Colon Cancer" and does not contain "Prostate Cancer":
        tweets_with_Color_Cancer.Add(tweet)

final_results = Concatenate(tweets_with_Prostate_Cancer, tweets_with_Colon_Cancer)
```